# jOOQ insert query with returning generated keys

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I installed jOOQ into eclipse, generated classes for my mySQL, but I still have problems to  write also some basic queries.

I tried to compose insert query with returning of generated keys, but compiler throws error

Table: tblCategory
Columns:  category_id, parent_id, name, rem, uipos

```
Result<TblcategoryRecord> result= create.insertInto(Tblcategory.TBLCATEGORY, 
    Tblcategory.PARENT_ID, Tblcategory.NAME, Tblcategory.REM, Tblcategory.UIPOS)
        .values(node.getParentid())
        .values(node.getName())
        .values(node.getRem())
        .values(node.getUipos())
        .returning(Tblcategory.CATEGORY_ID)
        .fetch();
```

tried also other differnt ways 
how to do it right way?

thanks
charis

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The syntax you're using is for inserting multiple records. This is going to insert 4 records, each with one field.

```
.values(node.getParentid())
.values(node.getName())
.values(node.getRem())
.values(node.getUipos())
```

But you declared 4 fields, so that's not going to work:

```
create.insertInto(Tblcategory.TBLCATEGORY, 
  Tblcategory.PARENT_ID, Tblcategory.NAME, Tblcategory.REM, Tblcategory.UIPOS)
```

What you probably want to do is this:

```
Result<TblcategoryRecord> result = create
  .insertInto(Tblcategory.TBLCATEGORY, 
    Tblcategory.PARENT_ID, Tblcategory.NAME, Tblcategory.REM, Tblcategory.UIPOS)
  .values(node.getParentid(), node.getName(), node.getRem(), node.getUipos())
  .returning(Tblcategory.CATEGORY_ID)
  .fetch();
```

Or alternatively:

```
Result<TblcategoryRecord> result = create
  .insertInto(Tblcategory.TBLCATEGORY) 
  .set(Tblcategory.PARENT_ID, node.getParentid())
  .set(Tblcategory.NAME, node.getName())
  .set(Tblcategory.REM, node.getRem())
  .set(Tblcategory.UIPOS, node.getUipos())
  .returning(Tblcategory.CATEGORY_ID)
  .fetch();
```

Probably, you're even better off by using

```
TblcategoryRecord result =
  // [...]
  .fetchOne();
```

For more details, consider the manual:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/

Or the Javadoc for creating `INSERT` statements that return values:

http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/InsertReturningStep.html

Comment: thanks, added preferred solution, but Eclipse still needs casting

Comment: @Charis997: It is usually not recommended to put answers in questions on Stack Overflow. It will be difficult for subsequent visitors to understand what's going on. Instead, you can "accept" this answer, or provide an answer yourself, if this one isn't clear enough

Comment: @Charis997: About the casting: You're right. That won't be necessary anymore with jOOQ 2.0. But it's still needed with jOOQ 1.6.9

Comment: Lets honour the code! Preffered solution posted in an answer below. Looking forward to jOOQ 2.0 Thx

Comment: It would be useful to have tableRecord.insertReturning(), so you don't need to map every single field in the record object to the respective table columns to be able to return a generated field value on insertion.

Comment: @andresp, you can call `set(record)`, to transfer changed fields from the record to an insert statement...

Comment: @LukasEder perfect. that works too. thank you.

Comment: Using `set(record)` causes a `DataAccessException` for me as the PK field of the table is set to null in the record.

This is a pity as having to use `set` on each individual field means that changes to the record risk missing changing the insert and not inserting new fields OR trying to insert to a column that's no longer in the record.

Answer (score 4):

preffered SOLUTION

```
  try {
    TblcategoryRecord record = (TblcategoryRecord) create
      .insertInto(Tblcategory.TBLCATEGORY) 
      .set(Tblcategory.PARENT_ID, node.getParentid())
      .set(Tblcategory.NAME, node.getName())
      .set(Tblcategory.REM, node.getRem())
      .set(Tblcategory.UIPOS, node.getUipos())
      .returning(Tblcategory.CATEGORY_ID)
      .fetchOne();

      node.setId(record.getCategoryId());

    } catch (SQLException e1) { }
```

Comment: You really shouldn't ignore that SQLException! If it's just an example, you may leave the whole try/catch block out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
YoutableRecord result = create
.insertInto(YOURTABLE)
.set(YOURTABLE.PROD_NAME, "VAL")
.returning(YOURTABLE.ID_PR)
.fetchOne();


int id = result.getValue(Products.PRODUCTS.ID_PR);
```