# JOOQ: Returning auto-incremented key?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

Given:

`CREATE TABLE foo (id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id));`

I'd like to invoke: `INSERT INTO foo VALUES()` and get back the generated key. I tried following the advice found at [jOOQ insert query with returning generated keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127378/jooq-insert-query-with-returning-generated-keys) but when I invoke:

`RoomsRecord record = db.insertInto(foo, Collections<Field<?>>emptyList()).returning(foo.ID).fetchOne();`

JOOQ returns null instead of the generated key. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in FieldMapsForInsert.isExecutable(). It flags the above query as non-executable but it is legal under MySQL. I filed https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/20

You can insert `NULL` as a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878416/14731). Furthermore, you must configure JOOQ to generate table "relations", otherwise `returning()` won't see the existence of primary keys and return null.

```
<configuration>
  <generator>
    <generate>
      <relations>true</relations>
    </generate>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```